# LARAVEL 10 unique search result in URL

Tags: laravel, search

I'm still a LARAVEL newbie so please bear with me :
I am using a search box with a get route: the box is automatically filled with a unique search item, pulled from the DB using autocomplete.
The controller does it's job perfectly in finding the required data, passing it to the 'show' view.
My issue is that the url displays the get parameters from the search, and not something like : 'admin/selected_word/{THE-SELECTED-WORD'S-SLUG} which is what I would look for as it is prettier, and most importantly SEO friendly...
What do I need to change to achieve this ?
-My present routes are as follows:

```
    Route::get('/modification/un-terme/choisir','choose_one')->name('choose_one');// Displays the search form ;
    Route::get('/modification/un-terme/autocomplete','autocomplete')->name('autocomplete');// route for the ajax autocomplet search & display ;
    Route::get('/modification/un-terme/revoir','review_one')->name('review_one');// route to get the related data 
    Route::post('/modification/un-terme/revoir','update_one')->name('update_one');// route to post the updated dat (not yet implemented...)
```

Many thanks

@brombeer
MAny thanks so Yes I was getting there myself so what whould the syntax be ?

```
redirect ('admin.words.review')->with ($searched word_data) ?
```

how would that change the resulting url to something like :
/admin/word-to-review/WORD-SLUG ?
I'm stillquite new to Laravel ... !
Many thanks for your patience
JM

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. Usually, you send a GET request to the server, and that contains parameters. Unless you write other code, there's no way to tern form paramters into route slug parameters

Comment: "_and most importantly SEO friendly_" Do search engines crawl your `admin/...` urls?

Comment: @brombeer:No you are right, specifiaclly for the admin, but my 'isue' is technically one that can be applied to other "areas" of the site ...

Comment: @nico Hase : thanks for your replyI ; I'll add some context

Comment: Nico Hase:
The searchform indeed has a 'get' action.
The controller then pulls the data searched term from the DB.
And then returns a view with the data as parameters :

return view('admin.words.word_update',compact($variables));
the view is returned with the previously sent query :
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mots-ou-expressions/modification/un-terme/revoir?_token=ntlpv4NKmrIvNkQFSACOo3PNpC1UbyWCxrMrmUss&search_language=fr&search=acquerir

Whereas I would want / expect the following url:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/mots-ou-expressions/modification/un-terme/revoir/acquerir

Comment: Don't return a view but `redirect()` to the URL you want

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section. Also, keep in mind that a common crawler won't submit your search form, so having a SEO-friendly URL for this sounds useless to me